# Spring Kafka - Consumers don't receive message sometimes

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a multi client spring boot application which send and receive kafka streams between its clients (which essentially means the application has a consumer and a producer in it). The configuration is as simply as it can be:

Inside @SpringBootApplication class (could be placed in a @Configuration class as well, but I didn't felt the need to create a new class only for that bean purpose):

```
@Bean
public NewTopic generalTopic() {
    return TopicBuilder.name("topic")
            .partitions(10)
            .replicas(10)
            .build();
}
```

Kafka producer and consumer configuration classes? We don't do that here, instead KafkaTemplate is injected in the class which is going to send the message:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
```

To produce the message, just invoke method "send(K, V) from KafkaTemplate":

```
kafkaTemplate.send("topic", "Hello World!");
```

To consume the messages, a @KafkaListener is used:

```
@KafkaListener(topics="topic", groupId="topic")
public void consumer(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

The properties are in application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=194.113.64.103:9092

spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Every single client runs all this code. The application is sending and consuming the messages, although, for some reason, sometimes the consumer receives the message, sometimes id does not (maybe the application sometimes does not send the messages? I doubt this one but who knows).
The interval between the received and unreceived messages are minimal: it varies between 1 - 10 seconds. So let's say I send a message once in a second (message being equal to "1" to "10"). Sometimes I receive "1", "2", "6", "8", sometimes "4", "7", "8", "9". It seems to be completely random.
Note that my server is running in another continent (U.S, all clients are located in South America).

Any thoughts?

P.S: I know placing my server IP is a huge security breach, although this is a temporary test server and nothing else than the kafka broker runs in there, so it is not a problem. I decided to keep the path in this post so everyone could test the described behavior.

Response to

> "./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe 'topic' --bootstrap-server
> 194.113.64.103:9092 --all-groups"

```
    GROUP           TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                           HOST             CLIENT-ID
topic           topic           1          0               0               0               consumer-topic-1-5b2ea195-f747-4d53-a17a-53c20a768a5f /168.194.160.183 consumer-topic-1
topic           topic           0          0               0               0               consumer-topic-1-5b2ea195-f747-4d53-a17a-53c20a768a5f /168.194.160.183 consumer-topic-1
topic           topic           4          1               1               0               consumer-topic-1-5b2ea195-f747-4d53-a17a-53c20a768a5f /168.194.160.183 consumer-topic-1
topic           topic           3          2               2               0               consumer-topic-1-5b2ea195-f747-4d53-a17a-53c20a768a5f /168.194.160.183 consumer-topic-1
topic           topic           2          0               0               0               consumer-topic-1-5b2ea195-f747-4d53-a17a-53c20a768a5f /168.194.160.183 consumer-topic-1
topic           topic           7          1               1               0               consumer-topic-1-c724077c-e911-4d6c-bb1d-1cba17c26a02 /168.194.160.183 consumer-topic-1
topic           topic           6          0               0               0               consumer-topic-1-c724077c-e911-4d6c-bb1d-1cba17c26a02 /168.194.160.183 consumer-topic-1
topic           topic           5          0               0               0               consumer-topic-1-c724077c-e911-4d6c-bb1d-1cba17c26a02 /168.194.160.183 consumer-topic-1
topic           topic           9          1               1               0               consumer-topic-1-c724077c-e911-4d6c-bb1d-1cba17c26a02 /168.194.160.183 consumer-topic-1
topic           topic           8          1               1               0               consumer-topic-1-c724077c-e911-4d6c-bb1d-1cba17c26a02 /168.194.160.183 consumer-topic-1
[root@my-vps bin]#
```

You can test my application by placing it in your Main class:

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
    return args -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            kafkaTemplate.send("topic", "Hello! " + i);
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you start multiple clients and show output of `kafka-consumer-groups --describe 'topic'` ?

Comment: Sure, give me a second

Comment: Also, its not clear to me where you are sending values 1-10.

Comment: My application is a JavaFX application, so it's an event triggered by JavaFX. You can place it in an endpoint as well (as pretty much anything like a CommandLineRunner)

Comment: Okay, but my point was that `kafkaTemplate.send("topic", "Hello World!")` sets a null Kafka record key with value of a string. Then your consumer would always consume `Hello World!`...  Where are you getting any numbers?

Comment: Is it possible that you have 2 (or more) consumers running? If so, each one will only get a subset of the records - look for `partitions assigned` in the logs.

Comment: I type the numbers in a client, then receive it in the other client. The @Bean I posted now do the same

Comment: Possibly, as the code posted here runs in all clients

Comment: Thanks, but you still never use value of `i`, and that sends to `sent` topic, not topic named `topic`

Comment: Sorry it was just a typo. Now it sends to "topic" and uses "i"

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shown in your code, everything is working as expected.

Your producer doesn't include a key, therefore events are round-robined across your 10 topic partitions. (sidenote: you don't need such a high replication factor). You are calling `send(String topic, V value)`, not `send(String topic, K key, V value)`

Your `@KafkaListener` has a hard-coded `groupId`, so since that's not any dynamic property, and Kafka consumers in the same group cannot read the same partitions at the same time, then by running multiple consumers (as shown by your 2 `consumer-ids` in the consumer group description), they individually will read different partitions. As mentioned above, in your producer, records are being distributed amongst various partitions.

You can see in the log output for the consumers which partitions they do get assigned, but you can also add a listener in Spring-Kafka for a partition onAssignment event to check this yourself.

> maybe the application sometimes does not send the messages

That is correct. Kafka sends *batches* of data, by default, not one at a time. You need to manually flush a producer to guarantee all events will be sent.

Notice that the end-offset column doesn't add up to a factor of 10, so only about 5 events were actually sent.

Comment: Ok, I get the root cause of my issue, but it still not clear to me what to do now. The method send(String topic, K key, V value), what is value K key? How it should look like? Also, if kafka consumers in same group cannot read same partitions at the same time, how a consumer can communicate with other?

Comment: added 'kafkaTemplate.flush();' after calling "send (without key)", now less messages are delivered @OneCricketeer

Comment: 1) `K` is a generic. You have `KafkaTemplate<String, String>`, so your `K` type is therefore a `String` . It can "look" like any regular Java string... 2) Consumers should not communicate with each other. Perhaps there is some misunderstanding about what Kafka offers here? 3) `flush()` method is correct, but you will want to do it after the loop, as well as within a Spring Boot lifecycle `@PreDestroy` method